# Smooth Lower Resolution Voxel Noise

Tags: perlin-noise, voxel, procedural-generation, procedural

After reading the blog post at n0tch.tumblr.com/post/4231184692/terrain-generation-part-1. I was interested in Notch's solution by sampling at lower resolutions. I implemented this solution in my engine, but instantly noticed he didn't go into detail what he interpolated between to smooth out the noise.

From the blog:

> Unfortunately, I immediately ran into both performance issues and
>   playability issues. Performance issues because of the huge amount of
>   sampling needed to be done, and playability issues because there were
>   no flat areas or smooth hills. The solution to both problems turned
>   out to be just sampling at a lower resolution (scaled 8x along the
>   horizontals, 4x along the vertical) and doing a linear interpolation.

This is the result of the low-res method without smoothing:
[low-res voxel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21hjf.png)

I attempted to smooth out the noise in the chunk noise array and instantly noticed a problem:
[attempt at smoothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9nQg.png)

The noise also looks less random now.

As you can see, there is an obvious transition between chunks. How exactly do I use interpolation to smooth out the low resolution noise map so that the border between chunks smoothly connect while still appearing random?

Comment: Hi and welcome! You may want to check out [GameDev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), which looks like it might have some relevant questions.

Comment: Should I move this thread to the GameDev SE section?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with their site, actually, I just did a quick search for "voxel smoothing" and noticed there were some similar looking posts. I would recommend checking those first to see if someone else has run into the same issue (and it should give you an idea of how to ask a question there). This *may* be a too broad for Stack Overflow but if that's the case maybe a mod can migrate it.